# Comparar se existe um ponto em uma determinada rota

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho uma página que calcula a distância entre o **Ponto A** e o **Ponto B**, porém preciso computar pedágios nessa rota.

Penso em ter um banco com as coordenadas (lat e lng) do pedágio e verificar se ele existe na rota, mas não sei como fazer.

Preciso retornar a quantidade de pedágios e valores dos mesmos no intervalo **Ponto A** - **Ponto B**. Qualquer ajuda será válida.

[image: Rota ponto A ao ponto B]

**JavaScript:**

```js
var options = {
   componentRestrictions: {country: 'br'}
  }; 
        var source, destination;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtSource'), options);
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtDestination'), options);
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });
  
      var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.9166813, -43.9344931);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: mumbai
            };
   
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);


        function GetRoute() {
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            //directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

            //*********DIRECOES E ROTAS**********************//
            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;
   
   
            var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //*********DISTANCIA E DURACAO**********************//
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, 
   
   function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distancia: " + distance + "<br />";
                    dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duração:" + duration + "<br />";

                } else {
                    alert("Não foi possível traçar essa rota.");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

O Google Maps não fornece a opção de ver quantos pedágios tem em uma rota. Ao contrário de várias condições do Google Maps, você não pode informar dentro de um código para que ele calcule a quantia de x locais em  uma rota específica.

Porém, você pode inserir uma condição para que TODAS as rotas que ele venha a calcular evitem pedágios. Basta você inserir `avoid=tolls` (Toll, em inglês, é pedágio) no link da chamada da API. Neste caso, o link ficará assim:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places,geometry&avoid=tolls" async defer></script>`

Lembrando que o Google não irá se proibir de mostrar caminhos por pedágios, apenas dará prioridade às rotas que não tiverem pedágios.

Documentação completa do recurso [neste link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=pt-br#Restrictions)

Ah, incrementando a resposta, o Google permite que você evite, além de pedágios, rodovias e balsas. Neste caso, é só colocar um ou todos os itens aqui:
`avoid=tolls|highways|ferries`

Comment: Preciso calcular os valores dos pedágios na rota, pesquisei e vi que somente com a API do Google isso não é possível, portanto penso em utilizar um banco de dados externo com a localização, preço, etc. dos pedágios e cruzar essa informação com a rota do Google Maps.

Obrigado.

Comment: @J. Arc pois é, seria necessário um outro banco de dados para ter esses dados. No momento, não conheço nenhum disponível para uso livre, mas dá uma olhada nesse site aqui: http://www.abcr.org.br/TarifasPedagio/TarifaPedagio.aspx

Comment: Gabriel Polidoro, muito obrigado pela ajuda, estou pesquisando sobre o assunto.